# Running two virtual hosts on Apache server 2.2.* always goes to first one's docroot for any server name

Tags: java, apache2, webserver

I have two virtual hosts in my httpd.conf file with separate docroots as shown below in same order.

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
DocumentRoot E:\docroot1    
ServerName www.development1.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.80>
DocumentRoot E:\docroot2
ServerName www.development2.local   
</VirtualHost>
```

Ideally when I hit www.development1.local it should show me the E:\docroot1 contents and when I hit www.development2.local it should show me the E:\docroot2 contents. Both these urls are set in my hosts file at 127.0.0.1

My problem is that whatever url I type either www.development1.local or www.development2.local it always shows me E:\docroot1 contents. If I change the order of virtual hosts in httpd.conf file then it shows the E:\docroot2 contents. That means it always goes to first virtual host.

Comment: Did you remember to enable name based virtual hosts?

Comment: How to do that Fredrik? I am new to this.

Comment: I see that you have already solved it but I still think it may be good for you to read this part of the manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Thanks Fredrik,

The problem got solved by using NameVirtualHost. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your server name is `www.development2.local`, which is not the same as just `development2.local`. When there is no virtual host matching the hostname in the URL *exactly*, the first virtual host will be used. Add

```
ServerAlias development2.local
```

if you want to use that name too.

Comment: Thanks Unbeli, my mistake while typing, its www.development1.local and www.development2.local which I try on browser and it takes me to docroot E:/docroot1 folder or docroot of virtualhost which is configured first in httpd.conf file.

Comment: dou you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive? You need one

Comment: ok thanks unbeli this solved my problem

I added these two lines in my httpd.conf file and it worked :)


NameVirtualHost www.development1.local
NameVirtualHost www.development2.local

now in both cases it showed different docroots.

Thanks for your help.